# Trying to port an Eclipse RCP application to Raspberry Pi

Tags: java

I have a pre-existing Eclipse RCP application that I'd like to port to the Raspberry Pi. In Eclipse Mars (4.5), there is support for cross-platform export to multiple Linux platforms (PPC, PPC64, PPC64LE, S390, S390x, x86, x86_64) but none for ARM.

Am I missing something or is Linux/ARM not supported? Since the Eclipse IDE itself apparently runs on ARM, I would expect this to be supported.

Answer (score 1):

I've done it whith this toolschain : http://gnutoolchains.com/raspberry/

But it's only for Windows to ARM support...
If it's your case, you'll find all necessary documentation on their web-site

Comment: Windows to ARM support is what I need. I have examined the toolchain you linked to, but I can't see in it how to port an Eclipse RCP/Java application to the Pi. Have I overlooked something?

Comment: Like said @flakeshake, for Java apps you don't need crosscompilation... but for C/C++, the link i send work for me. Just be carefull : raspberry-gcc-4.9.2-r2.exe is for `Jessie` distrib and raspberry-gcc4.6.3.exe is for `wheezy` one.

Comment: As I noted in my reply to @flakeshake, Java GUI applications using RCP/SWT do need to be cross compiled for each platform, because they use widgets native to each platform.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the Eclipse RCP written in and for Java ? The big selling point of Java was the "compile once , run anywhere" paradigm which should hold true as long your targets have a JVM available.

Raspbian supports several JVMs , the official Oracle JVM is even shipped by default.

**TL,DR** : You *don't* recompile Java apps and Raspbian supports Java apps already - **your app should work as-is.**

Comment: Not quite: RCP (rich client platform) is a platform for building GUI programs that have a look and feel native to the OS they are running on. RCP is in turn based on SWT (standard windowing toolkit). Because it uses widgets native to each platform, and it is not a standard part of the JVM, it has to be ported for each platform. You do in fact recompile Eclipse programs for each new platform.

Comment: Well, i guess you will have to compile everything from source then ? First SWT , then RCP , then your App ... i've compiled big projects on the Pi1 with a swapfile on USB HDD ... took 20 hours